Generate an HTML table in PHP with cells that span several rows
I wanted to achieve similar result as shown in below image.
Expected result:
enter image description here
Question: Looking for php html solution to create dynamic table along with Rowspan. I am facing issue to get the parent row and add the rowspan.
Your help is much appreciated.
Here is my php array data:
<?php
// Data dari database
$data = [
    [
        'nama' => 'Asyah',
        'hobi' => ['Bola', 'Voly', 'Renang'],
        'umur' => '10 Tahun',
        'keahlian' => ['Bernyanyi', 'Menari']
    ],
    [
        'nama' => 'Rian',
        'hobi' => ['Bola'],
        'umur' => '10 Tahun',
        'keahlian' => ['Main musik', 'Menari']
    ],
    [
        'nama' => 'Boby',
        'hobi' => ['Basket', 'Voly'],
        'umur' => '10 Tahun',
        'keahlian' => ['Bernyanyi', 'Menari', 'Coding']
    ]
];

?>

This is the script that I have tried:
<?php

// Fungsi untuk menghitung jumlah rowspan
function getRowspan($data) {
    $total = 0;
    foreach ($data as $item) {
        $total += max(count($item['hobi']), count($item['keahlian']));
    }
    return $total;
}
?>

<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nama</th>
            <th>Hobi</th>
            <th>Umur</th>
            <th>Keahlian</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($data as $item): ?>
            <?php $rowspan = max(count($item['hobi']), count($item['keahlian'])); ?>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="<?php echo $rowspan; ?>"><?php echo $item['nama']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo implode('</td></tr><tr><td>', $item['hobi']); ?></td>
                <td rowspan="<?php echo $rowspan; ?>"><?php echo $item['umur']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo implode('</td></tr><tr><td>', $item['keahlian']); ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php for ($i = 1; $i < $rowspan; $i++): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo isset($item['hobi'][$i]) ? $item['hobi'][$i] : ''; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo isset($item['keahlian'][$i]) ? $item['keahlian'][$i] : ''; ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endfor; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>


Do you have any specific question about this? Anything not working with the given code? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

<td rowspan="<?php echo $rowspan; ?>"><?php echo $item['nama']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo implode('</td></tr><tr><td>', $item['hobi']); ?></td>
<td rowspan="<?php echo $rowspan; ?>"><?php echo $item['umur']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo implode('</td></tr><tr><td>', $item['keahlian']); ?></td>

The problem lies in the 2nd and 4th lines, and I'm not quite sure why you want to implode them. You only need to display the first element of these two items. And, I recommend to use the short tag.
<td rowspan="<?= $rowspan ?>"><?= $item['nama'] ?></td>
<td><?= $item['hobi'][0] ?? '' ?></td>
<td rowspan="<?= $rowspan ?>"><?= $item['umur'] ?></td>
<td><?= $item['keahlian'][0] ?? '' ?></td>


Yes, you are right, but I have trowble with it short tag, so I changed with this code:
<td rowspan="<?= $rowspan ?>"><?= $item['nama'] ?></td>             <td><?php echo isset($item['hobi'][0]) ? $item['hobi'][0] : '';?></td>             <td rowspan="<?= $rowspan ?>"><?= $item['umur'] ?></td>             <td><?php echo isset($item['keahlian'][0]) ? $item['keahlian'][0] : '';?></td>
The problem is solved, many thanks @shingo

What about the following sources? Maybe you can try.
<style>
.header{background:#ccffcc;color:#006600;}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding:2px;
}

</style>

<?php
// variable containing an array of data
$data = [
    [
        'nama' => 'Asyah',
        'hobi' => ['Bola', 'Voly', 'Renang'],
        'umur' => '10 Tahun',
        'keahlian' => ['Bernyanyi', 'Menari']
    ],
    [
        'nama' => 'Rian',
        'hobi' => ['Bola'],
        'umur' => '10 Tahun',
        'keahlian' => ['Main musik', 'Menari']
    ],
    [
        'nama' => 'Boby',
        'hobi' => ['Basket', 'Voly'],
        'umur' => '10 Tahun',
        'keahlian' => ['Bernyanyi', 'Menari', 'Coding']
    ]
];


$html = ''; // Variable to store table row looping HTML

foreach ($data as $item) {
    $rowspan = max(count($item['hobi']), count($item['keahlian']));
    $html .= "<tr>
        <td rowspan=\"$rowspan\" valign='top'>{$item['nama']}</td>
        <td align='right' valign='top'>" . (isset($item['hobi'][0]) ? $item['hobi'][0] : '') . "</td>
        <td rowspan=\"$rowspan\" valign='top'>{$item['umur']}</td>
        <td valign='top'>" . (isset($item['keahlian'][0]) ? $item['keahlian'][0] : '') . "</td>
    </tr>";

    for ($i = 1; $i < $rowspan; $i++) 
    {   
        $html .= "<tr>
            <td  align='right' valign='top'>" . (isset($item['hobi'][$i]) ? $item['hobi'][$i] : '') . "</td>
            <td  align='right' valign='top'>" . (isset($item['keahlian'][$i]) ? $item['keahlian'][$i] : '') . "</td>
        </tr>";
    }

    $ni++;
}
?>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr class="header">
            <th>Nama</th>
            <th>Hobi</th>
            <th>Umur</th>
            <th>Keahlian</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody><?php echo $html; ?></tbody>
</table>


Please add some explanation such that others can learn from your answer. What did you change, and why?

Yes, it's pretty code. Very helpful.
